# Trying to consume messages with python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform

I am not able to consume messages with the below code. I am able to consume if I just directly `consOne.startLoop()`. What am I missing here. Appreciate the help.

```py
from confluent_kafka import Consumer, KafkaError, KafkaException, TopicPartition
from multiprocessing import Process
import sys


idlist = []
def setConfig(bootstrapServers, groupId, autoOffsetReset):
    consumerConf = {}
    consumerConf['bootstrap.servers']   = bootstrapServers 
    consumerConf['group.id']            = groupId
    consumerConf['auto.offset.reset']   = autoOffsetReset
    print(consumerConf)
    return consumerConf

def createConsumer(consumerConf, topic):
    consumer = Consumer(consumerConf)
    consumer.subscribe([topic])
    print("consumer subscribed to topic {}".format(topic))
    return consumer


# self.consumer.assign([TopicPartition(topic, partition)])

def startLoop(consumer):
    try:
        while True:
            message = consumer.poll(1.0)
            if message is None:
                print("none")
                continue
            elif message.error():
                if message.error().code == KafkaError._PARTITION_EOF:
                    sys.stderr.write('EOF Partition - {}  '.format(message.partition()))
                else:
                    sys.stderr.write('Consumer Error on Topic - {}  '.format(message.topic()))
                    sys.stderr.write('''-- topic        - {} 
                                        -- partition    - {} 
                                        -- offset       - {}'''.format(
                                                    message.topic(), message.partition(), message.offset()))
            else:
                print('Received message: {}'.format(message.value().decode('utf-8')))
                handleMessage(message.value())

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.stderr.write('Kafka Exception raised - {}  '.format(message.topic()))
        sys.exit(1)

    finally:
        consumer.close()

# body of the message or (message.vlue())
def handleMessage(body):
    global idlist
    idlist.append(body)
    print(idlist)

if __name__ === '__main__':
    config = setConfig('localhost:9092', groupId='group', 
    autoOffsetReset='smallest')
    consOne = createConsumer(config, 'test')
    # consOne.startLoop() Works!
    processOne = Process(target=startLoop, args=(consOne, ), group=None) 
    # doesn't work :(
    processOne.start()
    processOne.join()
```

---

```py
consumer = Consumer({'bootstrap.servers':'localhost:9092', 'group.id':'group', 'auto.offset.reset':'smallest'})
consumer.subscribe(['test'])

def startLoop():
    try:
        global consumer 
        print(consumer)
        while True:
            message = consumer.poll(1.0)
            if message is None:
                print("none")
                continue
            elif message.error():
                if message.error().code == KafkaError._PARTITION_EOF:
                    sys.stderr.write('EOF Partition - {}  '.format(message.partition()))
                else:
                    sys.stderr.write('Consumer Error on Topic - {}  '.format(message.topic()))
                    sys.stderr.write('''-- topic        - {} 
                                        -- partition    - {} 
                                        -- offset       - {}'''.format(
                                                    message.topic(), message.partition(), message.offset()))
            else:
                print('Received message: {}'.format(message.value().decode('utf-8')))
                # handleMessage(message.value())

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.stderr.write('Kafka Exception raised - {}  '.format(message.topic()))
        sys.exit(1)

    finally:
        consumer.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    processOne = Process(target=startLoop, group=None) 
    # still consumes message with startLoop() but not with processOne.start()
    # startLoop() 
    processOne.start()
    processOne.join()
```

Comment: add `processOne.join()` at the end

Comment: tried that too.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you use `multiprocessing` in the wrong way. [An example of the official document](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class).

> Make sure that the main module can be safely imported by a new Python interpreter without causing unintended side effects (such a starting a new process). [Safe importing of main module | Programming guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming)

So, It is necessary to start a process in `if __name__ == '__main__':`.

Comment: I modified the code and tried that. It didn't work. I think maybe the arguement is not pickable. I got that from the link you provided.

Comment: @neelabalan if the consumer object is not picklability, you should create it after the process starts. Inherts the Process class, create consumer in the run method

Comment: I have added the updated piece of code in my question. That piece of code doesn't work either

Comment: that worked. creating the consumer in the run method worked. Thank you very much appreciate the help.